# How do I stop bc from splitting lines?

Tags: biginteger, bc

I'm using `bc` from a bash script to do some quick and dirty BigInteger math but, when I bump up the scale, it starts splitting lines on me:

```
pax> echo 'scale=200 ; 1 / 4' | bc
.2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

pax> num="$(echo 'scale=200 ; 1 / 4' | bc )" ; echo $num
.2500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\ 00000 ...
```

How do I stop this from happening so that I can just get the number without any splits? The man page documents this behaviour but doesn't seem to give any options for changing it.

---

Actually, I'll step back and tell you the source of the request in case anyone has a better solution. I need an array of strings in C equivalent to the values 2<sup>-n</sup>, along the lines of:

```
static char *str[] = {
    "1.00000000 ... 000",     // 1/1 to 150 fractional places.
    "0.50000000 ... 000",     // 1/2
    "0.25000000 ... 000",     // 1/4
    "0.12500000 ... 000",     // 1/8
    : : :
    "0.00000000 ... 004",     // 1/(2^256)
};
```

I don't care what language generates the array, I'm just going to take the output and plug it into my C code. I do need the accuracy however.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to avoid using `bc` and `bash` in the first place?  A simple Python program would probably be easier than this.  Why are you sticking with `bc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on my system, the BC_LINE_LENGTH environment variable controls how long the output lines are:

```
$ echo 'scale=200; 1/4' | BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999 bc
.25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Setting BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 disables the multi-line feature (according to the GNU bc man page).

Comment: AArrgghh! Damn `less` and its case-sensitive search - I looked for `length` and found nothing. `LENGTH` would have taken me to _exactly_ the right section.

Comment: I prefer to leave case-sensitive the default and type `-i` from inside `less` to go insensitive, but many use the `LESS` environment variable to set `-i` by default (on *systems* where that's the default I confuse the hell out of myself by toggling it back on).

Answer (score 1):

```
localhost:~ slott$ python -c 'print "{0:.200f}".format( 1./4. )'
0.25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000


localhost:~ slott$ python -c 'import decimal; print 1/decimal.Decimal( 2**256 )'
8.636168555094444625386351863E-78
```

---

```
import decimal
for i in range(256):
    print "{0:.150f}".format(1/decimal.Decimal(2**i))
```

That's the raw values.

If you want to create proper C syntax, use something like this.

```
def long_string_iter():
    for i in range(256):
        yield i, "{0:.150f}".format(1/decimal.Decimal(2**i))

def c_syntax( string_iter ):
   print "static char *str[] = {"
   for i, value in string_iter():
       print '    "{0}", // 1/{1}'.format( value, i )
   print "};"
```

That might do what you want.

Comment: I need this to go to about 150 fractional digits (probably only 100 but some for safety) - is Python capable of this (specifically `1/(2^256) = 8.6361685550944446253863518628004e-78`)?

Comment: @paxdiablo:  150 fractional digits?  You're doing the math wrong, then.  Do some algebra and get rid of the division.  Python can handle an indefinite number of digits.  However, depending on a division operator introduces noise bits at the right-hand end of things.  A bad, bad design.

Answer (score 0):

```
% echo 'scale=200; 1/4' | bc | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\\'
.25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```